# can i use my tag in ckEditor5 sourceEditing?

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am using ckEditor5's source editing in React. When I copy & paste my html tags, some tags are automatically converted. For example, the button tag doesn't seem to be available, and

```
<p class="tit"> join </p>
```

is converted to a

```
<p> join </p> tag.
```

It is the same even if general html support is used. Is my usage method wrong?? My code is below.

[generalhtmlsupport.js]

```
ClassicEditor
                .create( {
                    htmlSupport: {
                        allow: [
                            {
                                name: ['div', 'button'],
                                classes: ['tit'],
                            },
                        ],
                    }
                } )
```

Aren't these settings done in this file?
The docs explain it as follows, so I set it like that in the file above.

```
ClassicEditor.create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
    htmlSupport: {
        allow: [ /* HTML features to allow */ ],
        disallow: [ /* HTML features to disallow */ ]
    }
} )
```

Do I need to configure it in ckeditor.js? Or should I set it in component.jsx where I'm loading ckEditor? I don't know what's wrong, please help me...